# Can Access VBA code be written to insert into a table from both a Query and a Form field?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a simple Activity Attendance Form that has a combo box for use to identify an “Activity” (combo box with a bound table) and an unbound text box to enter the “date” of the Activity.

[image]

When a command button (Generate Activity Roster) is executed, a Select Query is run using the Activity Name to filter the list of members who normally attend this activity (from a table: T:ActivityRoster).  The results are returned to the Activity Attendance form.  The user can then check off the attendance.  (I will work on the add/delete members from the Activity Roster later)

My challenge is now to Insert the Query fields (ActivityID, MemberID, Attended, AmtSpent) with the Activity Date into the Table- T:AttendanceHistory.

[image]

I have tried unions and other options from the web, but none seem to fit this scenario.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

new code:

```html
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit


Private Sub cmdSaveAttRec_Click()

   Dim actDate As Date, val1 As Long, val2 As Long, val3 As Boolean, val4 As Currency
Dim db As DAO.Database, rsIn As DAO.Recordset, rsOut As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "SELECT [T:ActivityList].ActivityName, [T:ActivityRoster].ActivityID, [T:ActivityRoster].MemberID, [T:MemberInfo].MemLastNam, [T:MemberInfo].MemFirstNam, [T:MemberInfo].MemMidIni, [T:ActivityRoster].Attended, [T:ActivityRoster].AmtSpent FROM [T:MemberInfo] INNER JOIN ([T:ActivityList] INNER JOIN [T:ActivityRoster] ON [T:ActivityList].ActivityID = [T:ActivityRoster].ActivityID) ON [T:MemberInfo].MemberID = [T:ActivityRoster].MemberID WHERE ((([T:ActivityList].ActivityName)=[Forms]![F:ActivityAttendance]![cboActivityName]))"

Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("T:AttendanceHistory", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
actDate = Me.ActivityDate.Value  ' Here you must replace this with the actual control name

With rsIn
.MoveFirst
Do
val1 = !ActivityID ' Or the column name of your recordset
val2 = !MemberID
val3 = !Attended
val4 = !AmtSpent

       With rsOut
           .AddNew
           !ActivityDate = actDate
           !ActivityID = val1
           !MemberID = val2
           !Attended = val3
           !AmtSpent = val4
           .Update
       End With
       
.MoveNext
Loop Until .EOF
.Close

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: (I'm not sure I understand you correctly) You want to insert a value and the values returned by a query executed in VBA... am I right?

Comment: the value on the form is the "Activity Date"...the values in the Query are from an Access Select Query and are shown in the "QActivityMembership subform."  These are the record fields I want to "append" / "insert" into the table T:AttendanceHistory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can acomplish this using VBA:

1. Read the values from the controls and insert them in your table
2. Execute the query directly from VBA, reading the values and insert them into your table

For option 1:

You should add a procedure to your form code:

```vb
sub readValuesFromSubForm()
   dim actDate as date, val1 as String
   dim db as DAO.Database, rs as DAO.recordset
   set db = currentDb()
   set rs = db.openrecordset("tbl_output", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)

   actDate = me.actDate.value  ' Here you must replace this with the actual control name
   ' Read the values from the subform controls:
   val1 = me.subForm.Form.txtVal1.value ' Replace with actual subform and control names

   ' Insert the new row into your table
   with rs
       .addNew
           !actDate = actDate
           !val1 = val1
       .update
       .close
   end with
   db.close
end sub
```

This only works if there's only one row in the sub form.

For option 2:

```vb
sub readValuesFromQuery()
    dim actDate as date, val1 as String
    dim db as DAO.Database, rsIn as DAO.recordset, rsOut as DAO.recordset
    dim strSQL as string
    set db = currentDb()
    strSQL = "select ..." ' Put your query here
    set rsIn = db.openRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    set rsOut = db.openrecordset("tbl_output", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
    actDate = me.actDate.value  ' Here you must replace this with the actual control name
    with rsIn
        .moveFirst
        do
           val1 = !val1 ' Or the column name of your recordset
           with rsOut
               .addNew
                   !actDate = actDate
                   !val1 = val1
               .update
           end with
           .moveNext
        loop until .EOF
        .close
    end with
end sub
```

These are only examples to put you in the right track.

Hope this helps

Comment: awesome code...option 2 fits my situation, but ran into some issues:

Comment: 1.  stopped on Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)   shows "rsIn = nothing

Comment: 2.  Activity Date shows 4/18/15 but actDate = 12:00:00 AM

Comment: error 3061 too few parameters expected 1  stopped on Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly) shows "rsIn = nothing –

Comment: also reintroduced SQL query into access query and runs fine.